# Inconsistent equations

Tags: linear-algebra

$u+v+w=2$(1)

$2u+3w=5$(2)

$3u+v+4w=6$(3)

In such equations we do not have any solution, because adding first and second equations we get $1=0$. And they are called inconsistent. From geometry i can say three plane that are not parallel has to intersect at one point. What is causing that?

Comment: Three non parallel planes do not necessarily intersect at one point : [Example](http://image.mathcaptain.com/cms/images/88/intersection-three-planes-three-lines.jpg).

Comment: A [slightly better example](http://geomalgorithms.com/Pic_3-planes.gif) (the bottom middle one).

Answer (score 2):

Let $$A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 4 
  \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$y = [ 2, \ 5, \ 6]^T$$
Your problem is find $x$, where $Ax= y$, but $A^{-1}$ does not exist since rank$(A) = 2$. Geometrically, the fact that $A^{-1}$ does not exist, means that the three vectors given in the columns (or rows) live in a 2D space.  You get no solution (rather than infinitely many solutions) when additionally, $y$ is not in the $2$d space spanned by the columns of $A$.

Comment: I have edited .

Answer (score 2):

Here is an image of the three planes described by your equations.

[image: 3 planes intersecting]

As you can see, the three lines formed by planes 1-2, 1-3 and 2-3 do not intersect in a single point.

[Here](https://ggbm.at/GSkfmbB6) you can interact with a dynamic version of the picture.

Comment: [You couldn't rotate that to get a side view?](http://i.imgur.com/Z2PLedh.png)

Comment: I tried a better view, but the planes form a little angle. But here you can interact with a dynamic version: https://ggbm.at/GSkfmbB6